# Which IIS config causes the "405 Method not allowed" error for specific calls?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

In our current WebAPI calls, only a few specific ones are returning the 405 error message (**405 Method not allowed**), the rest are working okay. The ones that are failing are only failing in a specific environment, in all the other environments all calls are returning 200 and everything is kosher.

Which IIS setting or system setting can cause this ? I am zooming in on this because this looks more like a systems/config issue.

```
Request URL : <hostname/GetAllStuff?userId=johndoe&sortByCustom=CreatedDate&sortByOrder=desc
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
    Remote Address: 172.72.78.33:443
    Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Allow: GET,POST,DELETE,PUT
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Content-Length: 136
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2018 17:16:28 GMT
    Expires: -1
```

The Response looks like this. What is strange is that ALL the API calls are 1.0 (api-version: 1.0) yet only a couple of calls throw this error and that too in a specific environment.

{
                "Error": {
                                "Code": "UnsupportedApiVersion",
                                "Message": "The requested resource with API version '1.0' does not support HTTP method 'GET'."
                }
}

Comment: enable `Failed Request Tracing` and look for the module failing

Comment: Not of much help <Data Name="ContextId">{97000671A-0000-FT01-B33F-84710C7456YB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ManagedPipelineHandler</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">128</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">405</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Method Not Allowed</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data> ----- It does say that the ManagedPipelineHandler is the one that failed.

Comment: Is your AppPool on `Integrated Mode` or `Classic Mode`?

Comment: It is Integrated Mode, I just confirmed it.